# How to create a submodule with libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to work out how to create a submodule with libgit2sharp.  It's not obvious from looking through the code and I can't find a test that does this.  Any help appreciated.

Essentially, I'm trying to do the equivalent of this:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:user/project.git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not implemented yet.

A work in progress pull request (**[#482](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/482)**) has been opened to tackle this.

Make sure to subscribe to it in order to be notified of its future progress.

Comment: Thanks.  Any other way of doing this at present without shelling out to git?  I'm not averse to doing a bit of heavy lifting.

Comment: Without shelling out to git -> I'm afraid there isn't

Comment: As the PR hasn't been updated in a while, you could chime in and give us a hand implementing this ;-) We'd gladly support you in this process.

Comment: I thought I had, but obviously didn't hit post.  I'll be on there in a minute.